# Inserting an image inside a video every few frames using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Can I use FFMPEG to insert an image every 20 frames in a video? 
I'm trying to create a subliminal message experiment and I thought it would be an easy way to make it but I can't find anything online.

I tried to make something myself and created a script that:
1.splits a file into audio and video files
2.splits the video into frames
3.overwrites every 20th image in the sequence with the message image
4.re-encoding the video
5.concatenating it with the original audio

this works but it's way more disk space consuming to be comfortable, is there a better way to do this?
any advice or thought would be happily welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your message image is the same resolution as the video. Then run

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i msg.png
   -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=enable='not(mod(n,20))':shortest=1[v]"
   -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy out.mp4
```

This will imprint the image on the very first frame as well. To avoid that,

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i msg.png
   -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=enable='if(gt(n,0),not(mod(n,20)),0)':shortest=1[v]"
   -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: I get an error: "Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0][1]overlay=enable='if(gt(n,0),not(mod(n,20)),0)':shortest=1[v]." 
for the second command, the first one isn't suitable because the imprint on the first frame is a problem.

Comment: Corrected typo.

Comment: works like a charm!
tell me something, if I insert a message with transparent background, is it possible to overlay it every X frames instead of overwriting the frame?

Comment: Yeah, if the FG has transparency, the BG will show through in those (transparent) areas.

Comment: How to make the image last for 2 seconds?